# Laptop gets very hot when use web browser

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop (intel 9th gen core i7, 16GB RAM) with a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 graphic card that gets very hot when navigate in youtube or other heavy sites. I guess this is because graphic card, I had same problem in the past with Linux and unsuported drivers, but currently

I have instaled Windows 10 with latest nvidia drivers, but problem continues. What driver should I install?

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to the driver; only one driver can be used, which is the one Nvidia released.  Since you have a slightly older card, the current driver release is fine, and your cooling problems are connected to your mobile device, likely with poor circulation.  Unless the machine is overheating, there isn't much you can do about it since laptop coolers don't do a great deal.

Comment: Possibly you can make the laptop use the on-board Intel graphics 'card' instead. Also you can install something like HWInfo to confirm what gets hot.

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop becomes too hot, the first step is to find out whether
the problem is with the CPU or the GPU.

You may use for that one of the products from the article
[7 Best Tools to Check GPU and CPU Temperature on Windows Computer](https://geekflare.com/check-cpu-temperature-windows/),
which also explains in detail the problem.

General steps you can take :

- Use a cooling pad
- Assure that all air passages are clean
- If your environment is dusty, cleaning the interior might help
- If the above didn't help, and once you know if the problem is with the
  CPU or the GPU, then a repairman might verify its thermal paste or
  replace its cooling fan by a better one (if possible).